# mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql

tengo el siguiente código donde estoy validando receipts en un api y luego hago un update en mi base de lo que haya cambiado de ese receipt; lo que me esta pasando es que en este momento en la base tengo más de 1000 resultados pero me esta actualizando solo uno después de que hace la verificación en la api, actualiza uno y tira un warning y no hace nada más.

> El error es. Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in /var/www/custom-webservices/public/lemonchilli/cron/cron.php on line 23

```
require_once '../db_connect.php';

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM jsonapple WHERE status='freetrial' AND expires_date_formatted_pst < (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY) OR status='Active' AND expires_date_formatted_pst < (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY) OR status='freetrial' AND auto_renew_status='false'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$sql = '';

if ($result) {

$count = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $count++;
    $latest_receipt = $row["latest_receipt"];

    $url = 'https://xxx/apple/verifyReceipt';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'token=xxx&receiptb64=' . $latest_receipt . '');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //print $result;
    curl_close($ch);

    if (($count % 200) == 0) {
        sleep(5);
    }

    $obj = json_decode($result, true);

    if ($obj["auto_renew_status"] == 1) {
        $auto_renew_status = 'true';
    } else {
        $auto_renew_status = 'false';
    }

    $status = $obj["status"];
    if (isset($obj["expiration_intent"])) {
        $expiration_intent = $obj["expiration_intent"];
    } else {
        $expiration_intent = '';
    }
    if (isset($obj["is_in_billing_retry_period"])) {
        $is_in_billing_retry_period = $obj["is_in_billing_retry_period"];
    } else {
        $is_in_billing_retry_period = '';
    }


    if ($status == 0 || $status == 21006) {

        if ($status == 21006) {
            $status_row = 'Expired';
        } else {
            if ($obj["auto_renew_status"] == 1 && $obj["latest_receipt_info"]["is_trial_period"] == 'true') {
                $status_row = 'Active';
            }
            elseif ($obj["auto_renew_status"] == 0 && $obj["latest_receipt_info"]["is_trial_period"] == 'true') {
                $status_row = 'FreeTrial';
            }
            elseif ($obj["auto_renew_status"] == 1 && $obj["latest_receipt_info"]["is_trial_period"] == 'false') {
                $status_row = 'Active';
                $payment    = 1;
            }
            elseif ($obj["auto_renew_status"] == 0 && $obj["latest_receipt_info"]["is_trial_period"] == 'false') {
                $status_row = 'Expired';
            }

        }

    } else {
        $status_row = 'Review response';
    }
    $sql .= "UPDATE jsonapple SET status='$status_row', expiration_intent='$expiration_intent', auto_renew_status='$auto_renew_status', is_in_billing_retry_period='$is_in_billing_retry_period', status_code ='$status', payment='$payment' WHERE latest_receipt='$latest_receipt'; ";
}


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Successfully" . $sql . "<br>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
} 

$conn->close();
```

[image: Consulta en mysql]

Comment: Cual es la linea?

Comment: Es esta. while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

Comment: puedes añadir un var_dump() de $result? creo que el error esta siendo en la consulta

Comment: si me devuelve Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in /var/www/custom-webservices/public/lemonchilli/cron/cron.php on line 23 y despues una sola consulta, probe en el while que me traiga todos los $latest_receipt = $row["latest_receipt"]; y también me esta mostrando uno solo y el warning.

Comment: y si ejecutas la consulta en phpmyadmin que te devuelve?

Comment: Ahí subí la imagen de la consulta.

Comment: Has probado "while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())"?

Comment: Ya descubrí que era; un compañero vio donde estaba el problema: estaba repitiendo la variable de resultado en el while y en el curl, estaba sobre escribiendo la variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diganle al junior que está usando $result = curl_exec($ch);
que $result es la misma variable que está usando en mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) eso se lo hace explotar.